# take a screenshot in java and save it on desktop

Tags: java, screenshot

I write a code to capture screenshot in java in windows 7.
This screenshot is saved in my workspace.

**I want this screenshot to be saved directly to desktop.**

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;     
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FullScreenCaptureExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            String format = "jpg";
            String fileName = "FullScreenshot." + format;

            Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));

            System.out.println("A full screenshot saved!");
        } catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give a path to your desktop in your `fileName` variable??

Comment: will you please give me sample example.Thanks

Comment: what did you try? we are not here to do your work

Comment: @swe,I respect you.Did i say to YOU to do my work?This is a platform where we discuss problems and find solution.I think this is not an appropriate place for you.I advice you to keep your thoughts and pardon all stackoverflow users.Respect others also.

Comment: @cdaiga give answer to my problem.@swe I think you are a foolproof programmer who do not understand other errors.I again advice you to pardon all stackoverflow users

Comment: @saksham this is a platform for enthusiastic programmers, not for people not willing to read documentation or to learn to program.

Comment: @saksham i am sorry, but i do not take any advice of how to use this platform of a user who just registered to ask a question without text to make others do his work. i am sorry, but YOU are the one beeing wrong of the both of us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the right file name if you want it to be saved on your desktop. It should include the path to your desktop. Say for example your desktop could be accessed via: `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop`, then you should replace the statment:

```
String fileName = "FullScreenshot." + format;
```

with:

```
String deskTopPath = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop";
String fileName = deskTopPath + "\\" + "FullScreenshot." + format;
```

**Take note:** If you want to take and save multiple shots then you should make the file name `FullScreenshot` unique for each shots. Devise a good strategy to make the `FullScreenshot` name to be unique (like appending the date time to that string).

Comment: I want to add time with image name for the uniqueness of image name.how can i do that?

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis();  Done.Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is not correct. NOBODY guarantees, that the place in the filesystem holding the users desktopfolder is c:\users... You have to use environment parameters or special folders.

Comment: I gave an example on Windows OS. He understood the logic of the answer! The other parameters you are citing are not necessary here!